# Connecting to Local version of Hyperledger Fabric through VSCode extension

Tags: ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

Following the tutorial here and trying to run a local version of Commercial Paper using the basic-network running on my local system:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform

Running against VSC 1.37.1 on Mac OSX 10.14.6 with all the requisite software installed.

The docs clearly say:

```
Connecting to another instance of Hyperledger Fabric

The extension allow you to connect to any Hyperledger Fabric instance and perform some operational tasks. The tasks available are: install, instantiate and registering and enrolling identities.

To connect to a Hyperledger Fabric instance on the Fabric Environments panel click the + button. This will ask you for JSON node files that describe how to connect to a Hyperledger Fabric Node i.e. peer, orderer, or certificate authority.
```

I have basic network running with active docker containers for ca, couchdb, orderer and peer0

Question -- how do I connect to this fabric -- what JSON files do I add to the `Fabric Environments` panel?

I'm not interested in using the local fabric the extension has -- I want to use my local fabric.

How? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The readme https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/blob/master/README.md provides details about how to create node files that represent your orderers/peers/cas for your own remote fabric.

However if your remote fabric uses TLS then the information is a bit sparse, see https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues/1319 for more information.

Comment: RE: creating node files -- while the first doc above lists the contents of the files, the docs however don't directly say what to name the files so can you confirm: fabric-peer.json; fabric-ca.json; fabric-orderer.json; peer.json; orderer.json? Or what?

Comment: It could be that the name of the file isn't important. it's the type field that describes what type of node it is. I haven't actually tried it myself but would suggest raising a further issue if the name of the file turns out to be important.